# How to delete an object by pressing a button with onClick via mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

There is code with GraphQL in bff and in the application part. This function is described as follows:

shema.js:

```
type Mutation {
  deleteCart(id: Int): [Cart]
}
```

index.js:

```
deleteCart: (_, args) => {
  carts = carts.filter((c) => c.id !== args.id);
  return carts;
}
```

As declared in query:

```
export const CART_ITEMS = gql`
mutation DeleteCart ($id: Int) {
  deleteCart(id: $id) {
    id, title, text, size, price, image
  }
}`
```

It's also not entirely clear how to implement triggering via button clicks `onClick`.

When I try to do this inside the GraphQL graphical interface, I get an error:

> Assignment to constant variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably defined `carts` as a `const` somewhere else in your code - your error is likely occurring when you do `carts = carts.filter((c) => c.id !== args.id);` Replace your original creation of `cart` with `let` instead of `const`